# Python: to_csv for decoded dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, decode

I have a text file that has encoded strings.
I am decoding them using `urllib.parse.unquote(string_df.encoded_string)` and storing it in a dataframe.

I want to export this dataframe to a text file.
However, it just adds garbage values.

For example:
Encoded String: %D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0...

Decoded using `urllib.parse.unquote` : спасо-преображенский собор

Exported value in text file: ?????-?????????????? ?????

I have tried exporting in an excel file using `to_excel` but when I open the excel file, it gives illegal character error.
Also tried using `numpy.savetxt` but it gives the same ?????-?????????????? ?????.

Anyway I can export it to a flat file and still have the desired "спасо-преображенский собор" result?

Comment: I decoded it the given text before placing them in a simple dataframe and used `to_excel` to export it, and it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a character-encoding problem, make sure your CSV file is opened as 'UTF-8' or other compatible encoding, not ASCII, as 'спасо-преображенский собор' are cyrillic and not latin characters.